# Restoring a deleted query in ADO

Tags: azure-devops

We have a project where a lot of queries have been deleted, I can see them in the query recycle bin. When i try to restore them it just says 'Unable to restore'.
If I delete a query then i am allowed to restore it.

Strange thing is, i seem to be one of very few people who can see that view, even a project collection admin user can't see the view, it just redirects them back to the query view.

So my questions are -
How is the query recycle bin secured, or is a feature that is hidden for some users?
Who is able to restore queries, or can you only restore your own?

Comment: You can try to test it with different users who have various permissions by using a REST API documented here: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/queries/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#undelete-a-query-or-folder